# Restore a terminated ec2 instance from a snapshot

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I accidentally terminated an ec2 instance, but I have several snapshots of its volume.

I created a new ec2 instance and I want to have an identical environment (files, installed programs) to the previous instance when the snapshot was taken. I tried creating detaching the volume of the new instance and attaching a volume created from the snapshot, but this did not work.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=42437)

Comment: These steps work. I actually was trying to follow these steps before, but I set the wrong subregion for the volume so I could not attach it to the instance, which was in a different subregion.

Comment: Love it when my old posts still help people years later.